# svg-pan-zoom not working 100% of the time

Tags: javascript, svgpanzoom

I use the svg-pan-zoom library (https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom), and it works about 75% of the time on a page on my site (both in Chrome and Firefox, latest versions).

Because Im assuming that this is due to some misconfiguration on my part, I was wondering if I made an error, or if there are specific scenario's that may be causing this.

My code:

```
(function (mw, $) {

   $(document).ready(function () {

        panZoomInstance = svgPanZoom('#stylometricanalysis-svg1', {
            zoomEnabled: true,
            controlIconsEnabled: true,
            fit: true,
            center: true,
            minZoom: 0.1
        });

        panZoomInstance = svgPanZoom('#stylometricanalysis-svg2', {
            zoomEnabled: true,
            controlIconsEnabled: true,
            fit: true,
            center: true,
            minZoom: 0.1
        });

    });

}(mediaWiki, jQuery));
```

The error:

```
145 TypeError: this.options.svg.createSVGMatrix is not a function
```

Library version: 3.2.9

```
<object class='stylometricanalysis-image' id='stylometricanalysis-svg1' type='image/svg+xml' data='/some/path/to/svg/file.svg'>Your browser does not support SVG files, and so your visualization cannot display</object>

<object class='stylometricanalysis-image' id='stylometricanalysis-svg2' type='image/svg+xml' data='/some/path/to/svg/file.svg'>Your browser does not support SVG files, and so your visualization cannot display</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SVG content is loaded dynamically. 
Which means that sometimes SVG content is available when JS kicks in, sometimes not. And when it's not - you get errors.

You have to init svgPanZoom only after your SVG content got loaded. Check [this example with dynamic SVGs](http://ariutta.github.io/svg-pan-zoom/demo/dynamic-load.html) to see how you can do that. But basically before initializing svgPanZoom you have to check if your SVG got loaded, and if not then listen for load event.